# korn shell Store for loop output "values" in array and pass to another loop

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, aix

Need help with array in korn shell. I need to pass the values from first for loop to 2nd loop.

The first loop returns
/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5
/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5.8
/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5.8

Then I am  greap "uniq" values. So I am want to pass the following uniq values
/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5
/opt/IBM/db2/V11.5.8

But, my script only pass the last values. Any help that would be great.

```
db2instance=`ps -eaf | grep db2sysc |grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | sort`
for instance in ${db2instance}; do
       set -A db2dirpath
       db2dirpath=$(su - $instance -c db2level| grep "Product is installed at" | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/.$//')
do
DIRDB2=$(echo ${db2dirpath[@]} | uniq)
for db2dir in "${DIRDB2[@]}"
do
      su - $instance -c "/db/data1/Ansible/db2dirpath.sh $instance $db2dir"
done
```

Comment: One issue I can see is that the line `DIRDB2=$(echo ${db2dirpath[@]} | uniq)` is only going to give one line of output, as the echo will put all of the entries in the db2path array on a single line, and uniq will find this line unique and so will output it.

Comment: Can you edit an example output of the su - $instance -c db2level output into the question (obviously with a suitable value for $instance) ?

Comment: A second issue is that the `set -A db2dirpath` assigns nothing to the db2path array, you want to append to the array, so probably want db2path+=( $(su - ...)).

Comment: Did you mean to use `typeset -A` rather than `set -A`?

Answer (score 0):

I am able resolve the issue. Below is the code that is working.

```
db2instance=`ps -eaf | grep db2sysc |grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | sort`

DIRDB2=$(
for instance in ${db2instance}; do
      db2dirpath=$(su - $instance -c db2level| grep "Product is installed at" | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/.$//')
      echo "$db2dirpath"
done
)
DIRPATH=$(echo "$DIRDB2" | sort -u | uniq)
for db2dir in $DIRPATH
do
      su - $instance -c "/db/data1/Ansible/db2dirpath.sh $db2dir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP seems unwilling to answer clarifying questions, this is just a guess.

```
# get a list of usernames that are running db2sysc. No need to sort them
# Assumption is the user names don't have unusual characters in them.
db2instance=$(ps -eaf | awk '/db2sys[c]/ {print $1}')
# set up an associative array to map dirpath to user name.
# probably should be called dpbath2user
typeset -A db2dirpath
# Loop over the usernames. Use associate array so we only record each
# db path once in the array.
for instance in ${db2instance}; do
       db2dirpath[$(su - $instance -c db2level| awk '/Product is installed a[t]/" {print $5}' | sed 's/"//g;s/.$//')]=$instance
done
# Loop over the paths
for db2dir in "${!db2dirpath[@]}"
do
      # process the path with the correct user name
      su - ${db2dirpath[db2dir]} -c "/db/data1/Ansible/db2dirpath.sh $instance $db2dir"
done
```